# How to single sign on for Linux RedHat server from windows desktop

Tags: authentication, portal, samba, security-roles, role

We are hosting our portal pages on a linux box.  I am supposed to implement a single sign on where the user logs into his/her windows xp desktop and that login is consumed by the portal and used to set the user role appropriately.  I really would like some answers on how this can work best.

Environment:
Jboss 4.2.2GA
Jboss portal 2.6.5
Redhat Enterprise Linux 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no way of doing this right.